# Trying to output in android app from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a project in which when a sensor is tripped it sends the data to the Firebase realtime database and then to be outputted in an Android application. Firebase creates a unique key for the data once it enters the database so I am unsure how to retrieve the data.

[Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoOgm.jpg)

[error that appears when app crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGmqC.jpg)

I have tried some code to output the data but it just crashes the App. The app opens onto the page that is trying to display the data.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference =
```

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

```
    Query lastQuery = databaseReference.child("sensor").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String message = dataSnapshot.child("Detection").getValue().toString();
            sensorValue.setText(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //Handle possible errors.
        }
    });
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question and please also provide a more detailed database screenshot.

Comment: I have updated this. No sign on "stack trace" in Logcat

Comment: At which particular line of code does that error occur?

Comment: String message = dataSnapshot.child("Detection").getValue().toString();

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of stacktraces. Copy-paste it into the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @RioghanDesmondButler I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whe you query the database to get the value of your `Detection` property, you need to loop throught the `DataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query lastQuery = rootRef.child("sensor").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String detection = ds.child("Detection").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, detection);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

I quote: "When you execute a query against the Firebase database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result."

The result in your logcat will be:

```
2019-04-22 13:58:58
```

Comment: works! thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome, cheers!